# White scene with a red point light

Tags: three.js

I want to have a scene that is completely white, except for a red point light. So basically whats currently black if no light reaches it should be white.
Any suggestion how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't imagine any better than using the pass of inverting the colors of the scene. The idea was taken from [here](http://jsdo.it/nyamogera/KGht).

```
const uniforms = {
  "tDiffuse": {
    type: "t",
    value: null
  }
};

const vertexShader = `
varying vec2 vUv;
  void main() {
  vUv = uv;
  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0    );
}
`

const fragmentShader = `
varying vec2 vUv;
uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;
void main() {
  vec4 color = texture2D(tDiffuse, vUv);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0 - color.x, 1.0 - color.y, 1.0 - color.z, 1.0);
}
`

var shader = {
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader
}

...
composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera));

var pass = new THREE.ShaderPass(shader);
composer.addPass(pass);
pass.renderToScreen = true;
pass.enabled = true;
```

and then in the animation loop you have to put

```
composer.render(scene, camera);
```

instead of `renderer.render(scene, camera);`

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/f6938rms/) example

PS If someone has a better idea, I'd like to know about it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Despite lack of your own code, you may start with `renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF, 1)`

This will set the scene "background" color to white. You will have to deal with any scene children depenting on their materials/textures etc

You may also have to work with possible shadows or use fog... so many possibilities without any code to start from.